# Windows 7 keeps losing network settings and being in an unidentified network every time I reboot

Tags: networking, windows-7

I recently changed my router to a Cisco 857 and had to re-setup my network. Everything looks great except that **my main workstation loses its IP every time I reboot** it.

It had added more networks when I made the changed in network sharing center with names like network 2, Local area connection #2 etc. and I wanted to clean it up so I renamed them and also merged networks on the screenshot below:

[image]

I am not really sure but I think this messed up everything. If I set up my static IPs all looks good but whenever I restart my nic changes to auto-negotiate and is in an unidentified network.

If I set my static IPs it remains an unidentified network but when I uninstall and reinstall nic's driver it successfully gets in "Home Network". I tried changing to a Work/Bussiness Network but I got same results.

I hope someone can point me out to the correct direction.

**UPDATE**

Sorry about reviving the topic but it seems that each time I clean install windows I get the same problem. I just did a double clean install of windows 10 and now, after a reboot, my PC boots to an unidentified network (with internet access).

Each time I manually switch to a static IP it seems it works fine but after a reboot I get an unidentified network. It seems weird to me that it takes it ~1 min to lose the yellow warning icon after booting. I think that it's something to do with my router. Do I have to clean the mac address table on it maybe? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I also have one more workstation with the same setup which is working without any problems. I also noticed that if i switch my ip to something else and then back to 192.168.1.2 it works ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to set a DHCP static binding in your Cisco router configuration.

1. Issue `ipconfig /all` command on Windows to locate your MAC Address.
2. Enter your router's configuration CLI and input the following commands:

   ```
   Router(config)# ip dhcp pool YourPool
   Router(dhcp-config)# host A.B.C.D M.A.S.K
   Router(dhcp-config)# client-identifier 1234.1234.1234
   ```

You may replace  `A.B.C.D` by your client's IP address, `M.A.S.K` by the subnet mask and `1234.1234.1234` by its MAC Address.

Comment: My other pc is working without problems so i dont think it is my cisco configuration!

Comment: I reinstalled windows and i am facing the same problem so i now think that is something about my router :S I tried your suggestion but i am getting the same behavior. Please help me more...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a security application (firewall, antivirus, etc.) blocking DHCP after a single DHCP offer is received. If uninstalling the NIC driver and reinstalling it results in a proper DHCP address assignment, but switching to static and then back to DHCP results in no address assignment, it's almost certain that (A) your router DHCP server is working properly and (B) you have a piece of software intercepting your network traffic and causing the DHCP process to fail in the process.

Disable any firewalls or "network shields" in any security software, including Windows Firewall, and see if the problem persists. If it does, uninstall your security software and test again.

Comment: I dont have any firewall excepts windows one. I use ms security essentials and i have one more workstation with the same setup which is working properly.